# PostgreSQL syntax error from backslashes?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, syntax, literals

I am debugging a sql file in PostgreSQL's pgAdminIII, and this statement creates a syntax error when executing:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "v"
LINE 81384: ...n.oid = c.relnamespace  WHERE     c.relkind IN (\'v\') AND n...
```

The statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getnextview()   
RETURNS name AS 
' DECLARE
   my_record RECORD;  viewName name; 
BEGIN
FOR my_record IN
  SELECT c.relname
  FROM pg_catalog.pg_class AS c
  LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace AS n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
  WHERE c.relkind IN (\'v\')
  AND n.nspname NOT IN (\'pg_catalog\', \'pg_toast\')
  AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
  LIMIT 1
LOOP
   viewName := my_record.relname;  
END LOOP;
RETURN (viewName);
END; '  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

Note, the pg_catalog and pg_toast also error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the full statement *does* change the picture substantially.

Your problem is the nesting of single quotes. If you use PostgreSQL's "[dollar quoting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING)" everything is a lot easier:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getnextview() 
  RETURNS name 
AS 
$body$
DECLARE 
    my_record RECORD; 
    viewName name; 
BEGIN 
    FOR my_record IN 
            SELECT c.relname 
            FROM pg_catalog.pg_class AS c 
              LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace AS n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace 
            WHERE c.relkind IN ('v') 
              AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast') 
              AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid) 
            LIMIT 1 
    LOOP 
        viewName := my_record.relname; 
    END LOOP; 

    RETURN (viewName); 
END; 
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' 
VOLATILE;
```

Comment: I tried that, but it still errored.  I then tried it with ''v'' (not a double quote, two single quotes next to each other) and it ran.  This wont change the 'v' will it?

Comment: Then you do need to show the full and exact statement you are running!

Answer (score 1):

This does the same exactly, just simpler:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getnextview()   
RETURNS name AS 
$BODY$

SELECT c.relname 
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class c
LEFT   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE  c.relkind = 'v'
AND    n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast') 
AND    pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
LIMIT  1

$BODY$
   LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```